# Tables associations best practices in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, relationship

Very new to Rails, have managed a few simple projects, but now stepping into more complex associations between tables and was hoping for some help.

The scenario can best be related to a sports match. Let's say we have

1) A Team (has_many players)

2) A Player (belongs_to team)

3) A Match -- now it gets tricky.

A Match will have: 2 teams, and 22 players (11 on each side) that take part in it. Also, associated with each player, will be their scores for the match (for example, Shots on goal, Goals scored, Points, etc.)

What would be the best practice to create this kind of association? Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a rather complicated problem. It also depends on how you will be using (querying) your data, which you haven't described. So it's kind of hard to answer this question.

Comment: I wasn't exactly sure how I should be querying the data. I figure I will add the "date played" as well as the "venue" to each match. That should be enough to pull matches (i.e. Show all matches played on Sept-27th-2012).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Models

app/models/team.rb

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :players, inverse_of: :team
    has_many :team_matches
    has_many :matches, through: :team_matches
end
```

app/models/player.rb

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team, inverse_of: :player
    has_many :player_matches
    has_many :matches, through: :player_matches
end
```

app/models/match.rb

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :players, through: :player_matches
    has_many :teams, through: :team_matches
end
```

app/models/team_match.rb

```
class TeamMatch < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team
    belongs_to :match
end
```

app/models/player_match.rb

```
class PlayerMatch < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :player
    belongs_to :match
end
```

### Migrations

db/migrate/create_matches.rb

```
class CreateMatches < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :matches do |t|
      t.datetime :happened_at
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

db/migrate/create_players.rb

```
class CreatePlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :players do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

db/migrate/create_teams.rb

```
class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

db/migrate/create_player_matches.rb

```
class CreatePlayerMatches < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :player_matches do |t|
      t.integer :match_id
      t.integer :player_id
      t.integer :player_shots_on_goal
      t.integer :player_goals_scored
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

db/migrate/create_team_matches.rb

```
class CreateTeamMatches < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :team_matches do |t|
      t.integer :match_id
      t.integer :team_id
      t.integer :team_points
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Edit1: @Mischa should share credit here! :)

Edit2: Sorry about the many versions, I totally underestimated this problem.

Comment: And how will you store shots on goal, goals scored??

Comment: Those fields go into the Match table. But that doesn't show up in the models, it's all in the migrations that form up the database schema. I'm going to add an example.

Comment: But with `has_many :players, through: :teams` you cannot store that on an individual player's level, because the association with a player goes through teams.

Comment: Exactly. That is an assumption that can be ironed out, though. It just seemed to be the case from the poster's wording.

Comment: I am saying your `has_many through` does not make much sense. Even less now that you posted a migration that contains `player_id` in the match table. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association If you still think that this is correct, please give an example how you will use this code.

Comment: The fact that you have `player_id` in the match table suggests `belongs_to` player, which is obviously incorrect. I think you need another model. E.g. `PlayerMatchScore` that `belongs_to :match` and `belongs_to :player`. And then in `Match`: `has_many :player_match_scores`. Something like that.

Comment: Hmm, yeah... thanks again. Let me try to come up with something better.

Comment: No problem. It's rather complication to model a situation like this. I am still thinking about how I would do it.

Comment: There you go! Do you think it could work now, Mischa? It still feels weird because the join tables have additional fields other than the ids...

Comment: I think it's either this or using an additional polymorphic model that works as an intermediary between matches and players/teams. Let us know how it pans out, Kopty.

Comment: This is fantastic. I wish I had more than upvote to give to you kind folks. Thank you for such a detailed and fantastic response.

Answer (score 0):

Player Has and belongs to Many Match

That table should contain the details of the player playing that match. For example for which team he played, from which minute (since players can change) etc.

Comment: Assuming a sport like Cricket for example in which players are fixed throughout and cannot change.